# Paypal adaptive payment error 58001

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am currently developing an adaptive payment system using paypal however a 58001 error keeps occurring

**Paypal Response:**

```
        {
        "responseEnvelope": {
            "timestamp": "2013-09-05T23:38:25.762-07:00",
            "ack": "Failure",
            "correlationId": "a72d1f30e37d4",
            "build": "6941298"
        },
        "error": [
            {
                "errorId": "580001",
                "domain": "PLATFORM",
                "subdomain": "Application",
                "severity": "Error",
                "category": "Application",
                "message": "Invalid request: {0}"
            }
        ]
}
```

**Paypal Request:**

```
$createPacket = array(
    "actionType" => "PAY",
    "currencyCode " => "USD",
    "receiverList" => array(
        "reveiver" => array(
            array(
                "amount" => "1.00",
                "email" => USER_EMAIL1
            ),
            array(
                "amount" => "3.00",
                "email" => USER_EMAIL2
            )
        )
    ),
    "returnUrl" => "http://localhost/",
    "errorUrl" => "http://localhost/",
    "cancelUrl" => "http://localhost/",
    "requestEnvelope" => array(
        "errorLanguage" => "en_US",
        "detailLevel" => "ReturnAll"
    )
);
```

And I can't figure out what's wrong. I have double checked everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had and extra space after currencyCode. It was "currencyCode " => "USD" when is should have been "currencyCode" => "USD" :)